# Compiling table of contents with memoir class yields block in position after the number when using the \part command

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

When I compile a table of contents using the memoir class for my phd thesis, and I use the `\part{}` command, in the output Part 3 and Part 4 have a little black block on the position immediately after the defining number. Also, Latex puts the first letter of the part title in the same position as this block.

Does anyone know what could be causing this, and where to correct it?

An example of the output:

[image: Output after compiling the Table of Contents using the \part command]

Comment: Try adding `\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{4em}` (or some other value), and see if that solves the problem. Otherwise, you'll need to reduce your problem to a minimal working example that demonstrates it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black box is caused simply by the overlapping of the part number and the part title. This overlap is caused by not allowing enough space for the number.  You can solve the problem by leaving more space.  This is controlled by the `\cftpartnumwidth` length. Set it to an appropriate value (`2em` seems to work nicely if you have fewer than 7 parts).

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{2em}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First}
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\part{Second}
\chapter{Three}
\chapter{Four}
\part{Third}
\chapter{Five}
\chapter{Six}
\part{Fourth}
\chapter{Seven}
\chapter{Eight}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of contents]